# File Browser Tree View MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tree

Hi guys my end goal is to create a selectable file browser using the Tree view in WPF. I had the tree view working a displaying properly, then I decided to move over to the proper MVVM structure, and the tree view will not display. Ive done some research, and have seen that I need to use HierarchicalDataTemplates with binding to make it work. I am just confused on how to have recursive functions that return complex directories with HierarchialDataTemplate (children).

Im currently using the TreeView type for the top level container for the tree view in the VM. Below is my ViewModel with the recursive functions to go through a directory. (If there is an easier way to do this feel free to let me know, It was my first attempt :) ).

```
        public void onBrowseCommand ( object commandInvoker )
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog win = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        Nullable<bool> result = win.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            string filename = win.FileName;
            rootfile= filename;

            rootfile = filename;
            int index = rootfile.Length;

            index = index - 4;
            rootfile = rootfile.Remove(index);



            //Get file version for text box
            var fversion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(filename);
            version = fversion.FileVersion;



            //get date created 
            DateTime fdate = File.GetCreationTime(filename);
            date = fdate.ToString();

            //Display Folder Contents
            showzip(filename);
            Window_Loaded();
        }
    }
    private void showzip(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            bool isZip = path.Contains(".zip");

            if (isZip)
            {
                dynamic shellApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application"));

                dynamic compressedFolderContents = shellApplication.NameSpace(path).Items;

                string destinationPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(path).FullName;

                dynamic destinationFolder = shellApplication.NameSpace(destinationPath);

                destinationFolder.CopyHere(compressedFolderContents);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    private void Window_Loaded()
    {
        string dir = rootfile;

        TreeViewItem items = new TreeViewItem();
        items.Header = dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
        items.Tag = dir;
        items.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        fillFiles(items, dir);

        foreach (string s in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            item.Tag = s;
            item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            fillFiles(item, s);
            FillTreeView(item, s);
            items.Items.Add(item);
        }

        foldersItem.Items.Add(items);
    }

    private void FillTreeView(TreeViewItem parentItem, string path)
    {
        foreach (string str in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path))
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            item.Tag = str;
            item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            parentItem.Items.Add(item);
            fillFiles(item, str);
            FillTreeView(item, str);
        }


    }

    private void fillFiles(TreeViewItem parentItem, string path)
    {
        foreach (string str in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path))
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            item.Tag = str;
            item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            parentItem.Items.Add(item);

        }
    }
```

Here is my XAML too. Thanks, just need a push if not a shove in the correct directiion.

```
        <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5,0,5,5" x:Name="foldersItem" ItemsSource="{Binding foldersItem}" >

        </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add some DataTemplates, yes.

You'd do something like

```
  <TreeView.Resources>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:MyFolderModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:MyFileModel}">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.Resources>
```

This is assuming you have a structure that looks something like...

```
  public class MyFolderModel
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<MyFileModel> Files { get; set; }
  }

  public class MyFileModel
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Of course, there's a bit more work involved, but that should hopefully help get you started.

Comment: I only have a simple class that has name, filepath, and a method. For this to work I need to create classes to contain both folders and files?

Comment: Yes, if you're trying to do the MVVM thing, you'll want to have classes that represent your objects.

This link has a couple different examples in it, which might clear it up for you:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: I still cant seem to get the tree to display.